# how to grant MySQL privileges only to a specific row

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, privileges

Imagine there is a student table 
**student(id,name,city)** 
I want to create a user A and grant permission only to update record where id=10.

`CREATE USER A ;` 
`GRANT UPDATE ON student TO A WHERE student.id=10;`

I tried this and it does not work.

Comment: I cannot find anything in the documentation which would suggest this is possible. What made you think it was - have you been set some task to restrict in the way the question suggests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No not a single row** but a view that contains a single row which will, in turn, will update the actual real table.

This can be done via specific table view per student (yes it will be a messy DB structure). Grant access to the view for this user only alow select/updates only and the primary key will be non-updateable. The main table will update itself when the view is updated.

```
CREATE SCHEMA `example` ;

CREATE TABLE `example`.`student` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL,
      `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `example`.`student` (`id`, `name`, `email`) VALUES ('1', 'bob', 'bob@bob.com');


USE `example`;
CREATE 
     OR REPLACE SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `student_1` AS
    SELECT 
        `student`.`id` AS `id`,
        `student`.`name` AS `name`,
        `student`.`email` AS `email`
    FROM
        `student`
    WHERE
        (`student`.`id` = '1');

CREATE USER 'student_1_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';

    GRANT SELECT,UPDATE ON example.student_1 TO student_1_user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';

UPDATE example.student_1 SET email='newemail@bob.com'; // note no primary key needed or allowed
```

Comment: That is very clever, but let’s be clear — this is not good database practice, and it does not scale to multiple users well. It is better to implement business logic like this with a second table of users and permissions and use actual business logic.

Comment: @vy32 totally agree! Could you provide your answer that avoids using views? And merges into a single table. Maybe using a trigger? This level of granular security should be implemented at the application, not the database level. But hey each to their own!

Comment: This actually not a practical scenario. I found some questions regrading this in my college . I ve searched every where to find a solution to these kind of security granting. I think this is the way we can do it. Views Would help.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/protect-your-data-row-level-security-in-mariadb-10-0/

Comment: the question itself is actually a wrong solution to a problem not shared